# Microsoft Edge - picture from external source not shown

Tags: wordpress, image, microsoft-edge, src

I have following code in my WordPress website:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5"><img class="img-fluid m-b-2" src="https://bwt.phpag.com/pimData/Images/hc/21/4245243.png"><img class="img-fluid m-b-2" src="http://localhost:8080/geha-printing/wp-content/themes/geha-printing-wordpress/images/geha-logo.png"></div>
```

My page: http://www.geha-printing.com/products/?Article_Number=4245243

First picture from external source (https) is not shown, second is shown without any problem. Do you have any idea why, or what can I do?

Issue is only in Microsoft Edge. IE, Firefor, Opera, GoogleChrome, Safari are OK.

Answer (score 0):

This must be an issue with your browser. I just checked, and everything looks perfect in Edge, Chrome and Firefox.

You might try to clear cache or [re-install Edge](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-reinstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10/)

Comment: Clearing cache really helped, thank you.
How can I mark your message as correct answer?